# Variadic template errors

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates

This is my first shot really playing with variadic templates. The following code doesn't have much use, it's just for learning purposes, but it shares similarities with `std::async` (which is what I set out to implement).

```
std::queue<std::function<void()>> functions;

template<typename Function, typename... Args>
void DeferCall(Function&& f, Args&& args...)
{
    functions.push([=]{ f(args...); });
}

void func(int x, int y)
{
    std::cout << x << ' ' << y << '\n';
}

int main()
{
    DeferCall(func, 1, 2);
    DeferCall([]{ func(6, 7); });

    while(!functions.empty())
    {
        functions.front()();
        functions.pop();
    }
}
```

I'm getting `'Args' : parameter pack must be expanded in this context` on the signature of `DeferCall`.

In addition that wondering how to make the above work in general, I have a question about how this can be improved: `f` and `args` are meant to get stored by value in the lambda, but since they are taken in `DeferCall` they could theoretically be `std::forward`ed which might end up being copied or might end up being moved. I don't think there's any way to do this with a lambda is there? I'm forced to copy I think. If I want to do this (and I do) I would need to make my own functor which allows it right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the parameter list of a function or method, the parameter pack must proceed the type of the object and occur *before* the name of the object. So change the relevant code to the following:

```
void DeferCall(Function&& f, Args&&... args)
```

Comment: Oh that was simple. But now there are other problems: `error C2662: 'void DeferCall::<lambda_97d60e9020ff3a02c66134a5991a741d>::f(int,int)' : cannot convert 'this' pointer from 'const DeferCall::<lambda_97d60e9020ff3a02c66134a5991a741d>' to 'DeferCall::<lambda_97d60e9020ff3a02c66134a5991a741d> &'`

Comment: @Dave [It compiles fine for me...](http://liveworkspace.org/code/4yc7Hy$2523)

Comment: Ok thanks. I guess it's a VS2012 bug.

Comment: @Dave wait what? VS2012 supports variadic templates?

Comment: I can only get clang to accept it: http://liveworkspace.org/code/1ym48C$7

Comment: @Cubic [link](http://aka.ms/vc-ctp)